# Scrapy returning NotImplementedError

Tags: scrapy

I'm running the following scrapy spider on Hostelworld.com, to retrieve:

- the continent, countries and countries urls on the first page
- the list of cities from a given country after having followed the country url

  ```
  def parse_page1(self, response):
      for sel in response.xpath('//li[@class="accordion-navigation"]//ul[@class="small-block-grid-2 medium-block-grid-4 large-block-grid-6"]/li'):
          item = HostelWorldItem()
          item['continent'] = sel.xpath('./../../@id').extract_first()
          item['country'] = sel.xpath('./a/text()').extract_first()
          item['country_url'] = sel.xpath('./a/@href').extract_first()

          yield item

          url = response.urljoin('%s'%(item['country_url']))
          request = scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse_dir_contents)
          request.meta['item'] = item
          yield request

  def parse_dir_contents(self, response):
      item = response.meta['item']
      item['city'] = response.xpath('//div[@class="otherlocations"]/li/a/text()').extract_first()
      yield item
  ```

I get the following error when running it, and I cannot find a solution to that:

```
scrapy/spiders/__init__.py", line 76, in parse
raise NotImplementedError
NotImplementedError
```

Thanks very much for your help!

Answer (score 4):

Scrapy `Spider` requires `parse()` method to be defined and you don't have one.

How scrapy.Spider chain works by default is by making a request to every url in `start_urls` with callback `self.parse`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to implement `parse()` method at [https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/master/scrapy/spiders/**init**.py#L89](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/master/scrapy/spiders/__init__.py#L89).